# extracting link details like Google and Facebook

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, facebook

I want to extract the link details like Facebook and Google. But the problem is that the detials (like the manin text and images) are not sure. Sometimes the main text is in p tag sometimes it is extracted from meta tag. So any thought on which places to search?

```
  http://forums.asp.net/p/1847212/5162336.aspx/1?extract+certain+part+of+text+like+google+and+bing
```

I pasted this link in facebook and the detail text it extracted was in p tag that was below another p tag which also had a text inside it. So how to decide this?

Answer (score 1):

If the website in question is [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) enabled, then you could parse the meta-data defined by that standard. Since it's the same system used by Facebook (and I believe Google+), you can probably expect a decent % of sites to support it. I wouldn't 100% rely on it, but a nice tool to have.

Comment: Wow.Thank you. Looks Great. But the sites I have used as an example non seems to have the tags used of Open Graph. And how to check whether the site in question is using Open Graph protocol or not?

Comment: The only way I know of is to parse the header and look for `og:*` metadata.

Comment: ok. Still seems good. As per my research I have found that facebook extracts details first from meta tag's content attribute if it contains text. If meta tag with content attribute that has text in it, is not present then it searches for the first p tag that has larger bit of string inside it. That has what I have found so far. Still not sure about the images. but I think it searches for images with the heighest width and height in the document and extracts it.